# Implementing Standards for Mathematical Practice in CCSS(M) (Proficiency Education)

Tags: common-core

I use the CCSS(M) and proficiency education to assess students. Is it okay to repeat the standards [here](http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Practice/) when assessing students for proficiency-based education? The idea of these standards in my opinion is to make them repeatable.

Proficiency-based education is typically assessed on a scale 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 where a 3 is proficient for any given standard. The idea of proficiency typically means once a student is proficient then they move on. In my opinion, the standards I listed above are repeatable and need to be integrated on their own. I am curious to see what others do who use proficiency-based education.

Comment: I don't think it is just okay, but is the intent. The practice standards are sort of meta-standards relative to the content standards.  They are intended to apply repeatedly grade after grade.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I just find it weird from a proficiency-based mindset to assess students repeatedly on the same standard. I always viewed the philosophy of proficiency-based education to be done with a specific concept once it is mastered and to move onto something new. Those standards are specifically designed to be repeated though as they are to be assessed throughout all grade levels when reading closer into it.